# Why is hotspot requiring me to go to the settings menu?

Tags: settings, browser, wifi-hotspot, data-connection, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I I just click the hotspot app it says checking my subscription status and flashes 'turning hotspot on' but then comes back and does NOT turn the hotspot on.

However If I go to Settings -> More networks => Mobile Hotspot I can turn it on there.  Subsequent to this if I click on the hotspot application icon. It says 'Turning off hotspot'  and it does actually turn it off.  However immediately clicking it again does NOT turn it on.

Is there any way to make it so the application icon itself 'can' turn the hotpot on without doing that from within 'settings'.

This is for a Samsung s5.
I'm using a (99 cents) mobile hotspot app that I downloaded from the play store.

Comment: What hotspot app is this? What phone do you have?

Comment: Added more info.

Comment: I don't know the app, and you haven't supplied a link. I would say your best bet is to contact the developer on this.